# Trying to connect java program to mySQL server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I try to run this code I get an error that says that I am missing the proper drivers, but when I downloaded a driver the error still occurred.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("108.167.137.42" ,"********", "********" );
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println( e.getMessage( ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to load jdbc driver using `class.forName()`.Refer this tutorial https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database

Comment: You need the driver for mySql, please load the driver. If you are stuck there are plenty of boilerplate code that can be found on google to do this.

Comment: If you want to remotely connect to database, make sure it's accessible from outside with the parameters provided.

Comment: `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://108.167.137.42",...);`

Answer (score 0):

The url should not contain only IP adresse it should look like this :

```
jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]]
```

So instead you have to use:

```
jdbc:mysql://108.167.137.42:3306/bd_name
```

---

[read more here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL, the JDBC connection string should be as follows:

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://108.167.137.42:3306/database_name";
String USERNAME = "root";
String PASSWORD = "root";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

Along with the change in the code as suggested, you might have to do the following change in your `my.cnf` file too or else you'll not be able to connect to your MySQL database.

```
bind-address = xx.xx.xx.xx
```

You need to restart your MySQL service, once this setting is changed. Hope this helps!

Comment: What `bind-address` has to do with the Connection?

Comment: @dosdebug, OP is using an external IP instead of usual! Hence suggested the change!